# Are RealTimeSync and FreeFileSync Automated?

Tags: sync, freefilesync, realtimesync

I know that one can create batch files and then use RealTimeSync to
automatically create a backup, but this process doesn't seem 100% automated
or either I am missing something.

What happens for me is that FreeFileSync automatically opens up and
compares the source and destination files and folders, and then that's it.

I have to stop what I am doing, go to the program, and press Synchronize.

Is this how this is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

The synchronization wouldn't happen automatically, i.e. I would have to press the Synchronize button after the scanning / comparison was completed because I was trying to get RealtimeSync to do two batch jobs at once by specifying two batch files in the Command Line. That would only do the scanning / comparison and nothing else.

When I only specify one batch file, it works.

I was trying to avoid running two RealTimeSync sessions because I want one hard drive to be monitored more than another one, but it looks like this is the only way to do it. (I know in one batch file I could have several jobs performed, but the Idle Time in RealtimeSync would be the same for all.)